# ProxyToServerConnection exceptionCaught in Selenium autotests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I couldn't solve this problem

Stack: Java8, Selenium 3.141.59, TestNG 7.4.0

There are autotests written in selenium, inherited and the devil will break his leg in their implementation. Recently, when running locally, the following burd falls into the console:

```
2022 10:44:34 AM org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection exceptionCaught
SEVERE: (DISCONNECTED) [id: 0x73ffd0c0, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:51452 ! R:content-autofill.googleapis.com/64.233.162.95:443]: Caught an exception on ProxyToServerConnection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Tag mismatch!
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:461)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1302)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Tag mismatch!
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:970)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:272)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1175)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1087)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1122)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:491)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:430)
    ... 15 more
```

and:

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:578)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2376)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:461)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:172)
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:177)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:963)
    ... 24 more
```

At the same time, the tests do not fall and pass, it's just that the entire console is clogged with this.

At work, there are white sheets of Kaspersky, including that it replaces its certificates.

In the Decorator, the devil will break his leg as well. If it is necessary I will throw off parts of its implementation.

So no one could help, I write here ...

What can be done to remove this error.